# How to make a REST API call from jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to make a REST API call from jenkins pipeline once a build job is finished. Since I'm new to the content, I'm unable to complete the build with my below script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('BUILD') {
            steps {
                echo 'Demo Staging Build Running'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            echo 'Demo Staging Build Completed'
            
            echo "Build Result: ${currentBuild.result}"
                        
            echo "Build Url: ${env.BUILD_URL}"
            
            def response = httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:9091/demo/jenkins-res'
            
            echo "Status: ${response.status}"
            
        }
    }
}
```

While running the script, I'm getting the below error:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 27: Expected a step @ line 27, column 13.
               def response = httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:9091/ucreator/jenkins-res'
```

Comment: You are probably missing a script{ } step around your groovy code

Answer (score 1):

Rectified the issue with a script tag surrounding the request

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('BUILD') {
            steps {
                echo 'Demo Staging Build Running'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            echo 'Demo Staging Build Completed'
            
            echo "Build Result: ${currentBuild.result}"
                        
            echo "Build Url: ${env.BUILD_URL}"
            
            script {
                 def response = httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:9091/demo/jenkins-res'
            }
            
            echo "Status: ${response.status}"
            
        }
    }
}
```